# Load balance prevent from seeing email

Tags: email, load-balancing

Some of our email are hosted with Network Solution, Yesterday we setup load balance on our WAN connection. Since we did it, our user cant log on to their web mail interface.

Each time they try to log on, they get a message saying that their IP adress changed so they need to log in again.

Any of you ever experience something like that with load balance? How would you fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the load balancing implementation. It simply balances load to both uplinks, without taking care that TCP connections from source X to destination Y always use the same WAN interface.

You need to configure your load balancer to perform load balancing based on source IP / destination IP pairs, so that a single pair is always sent out via the same interface.

You should ask your load balancer vendor if this is possible to do or not.

Comment: I suppose it will depend from the equipment used, but can you elaborate a little bit about that.
How you would balance the TCP connection. I'm not sur on how it could be acheived.

Does it have link with sitcky cession, cause I also read a little bit about sticky cession, but it not implemented on our equipment (by the way we use an EdgeMAX routeur from UBNT).
thank you.

Comment: Actually my first answer was a bit inaccurate, I have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. You put me on the right way. Unfortunnatly Ubnt does not support load balancing based on ip. We had to put a rule in the firewall that alway send https traffic on the same interface.